# How to remove an account from the Cloud code intellij plugin

Tags: rubymine, google-cloud-intellij

I have recently the [cloud code plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8079-cloud-code) for Rubymine and i was wondering how to remove an account so the plugin cannot access the projects associated with that google account.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is a **Tools** > **Cloud code** > **Sign out of Google Cloud platform** which will sign out of all the accounts listed in the plugin. So I suppose you can log back in only with the desired account

Comment: This is correct. We use the same set of accounts as your Google Cloud SDK has configured. There is no practical difference between having a logged in account for Cloud SDK and Cloud Code.